# Can't delete a Parse PFObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm having trouble deleting an object... Confused why it can't find it because I am already collecting data from it from Parse to the user's device. I'm getting 2 error messages. One for the first deleteInBackground, and then again for deleteEventually:

1) Error: object not found for delete (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.19)

2) runEventually command failed. Error:Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 101.)" UserInfo=0x17d16150 {code=101, error=object not found for delete}

Here's my code on how I am deleting:

```
PFObject *parseMessage = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

SentMessage *newMessage = [[SentMessage alloc] initNew:parseMessage[@"senderEmail"] :parseMessage[@"senderName"] :Kjell.savedData.userEmail :Kjell.savedData.userDisplayName :parseMessage[@"message"]];
                            [newMessage setTimeReceived:[NSDate date]];
                            [newMessage setTimeSent:parseMessage[@"dateSent"]];
                            [[[Kjell.savedData.recentUserArray objectAtIndex:j] conversationArray] addObject:newMessage];
                            [parseMessage deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                if (!succeeded)
                                {
                                    [parseMessage deleteEventually];
                                }
                            }];
```

any help would be great.

Comment: parseMessage should be alloc with className and not objectAtIndex. After changing it then try to firstly fetch it and if you are able to fetch then go for delete option.

Comment: did you solved this issue..i have been facing this issue from long time

Answer (score 0):

Once ensured that object really exist server side, check if ACL is property set for it, so that current logged user ( client side ) can affect that object for edit or delete